# Referencing javascript embedded resource but intellisense doesn't show anything

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, intellisense, embedded-resource

**I'm stuck...** I'm trying to reference a javascript file that has been embedded inside a third party assembly, but it doesn't seem to work:

What I've done:

1. I have a folder *RefAssemblies* where this library DLL with embedded javascript file is located
2. I added a project reference and pointed to this library assembly
3. I added a line in my javascript file where I want the reference to work ie.

   ```
   /// <reference name="ScriptName.js" assembly="AssemblyName" />
   ```

   I tried naming my assembly with name only, and also with full assembly name including name, version, culture and public key token. No difference.
4. Added my library assembly to my project's `web.config` inside `system.web\assemblies` (AFAIK that's the part where you have to add your assembly and make it *well-known* in your application) so I should be able to access it without referencing assembly at all just resource name. No difference.

And **yes** I was pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> after any change I've done so Visual studio refreshed Javascript intellisense cache. I even *unloaded* and *reloaded* my web project after I changed web project's `web.config`. Just so that Visual Studio would read the file and reload everything anew.

But still unlucky... And I'm not getting any Javascript Intellisense errors in the *General* output window either...

**I must be missing something...**

> ***Additional note**:
>
>   It may be helpful to know that I'm running **ReSharper 6.1.1000.82** within **Visual Studio 10.0.40219.1***

### Other things I've done afterwards

1. Uninstalled ReSharper from my machine
2. Reset Visual Studio by running it from command prompt using

   ```
   devenv /ResetSettings
   ```

   No luck either.

**Do you have any other suggestions I might do?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having odd problems with embedded resources. I have managed to get it working though by using the fully qualified resource name. You can find that out by using ilspy to open the assembly and then select the Resources folder, then the full name of all the resources will be displayed.

As i said i have gotten this to work in one solution, but in others it doesnt work and i have no idea why.. the non working solution has a diffrent structure where the diffrent assemblies are in diffrent folders, but i have nto been able to isolate that as the cause..

-edit-

After much trial and error it seems like the key thing to making embedded javascript references work is to **set the output folder for the project containing the reference to `bin` and not `bin\debug`.**

from what i can gather, there are no other settings or assembly references that affect the embedded resources, only the output folder of the project that has the reference. i'm guessing that the javascript language service is unable to find the assemblies with embedded resources unless they are in the private path or the gac, but i have yet do understand exactly where this binpath is set.

i've tried setting it on the project itself and on what i think is the actual language service exe, but to no avail.

i made a connect issue here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/770185/js-references-to-embedded-files-require-the-referencing-project-to-have-outputpath-bin

Comment: I guess this is a bug anyway. And web projects already set output to `bin` folder. No `Debug/Release` there... That particular referenced assembly got deployed to `bin` folder on every build so I'm not sure your solution works in my case?

Comment: maybe, did you use the reflected resource/ assembly name as well?

Comment: To tell you the truth, his is so many months ago I don't remember all those details any more. It was a PoC project that that I've already removed from my machine. So I can't test this anymore.